# How do I label pipelines in GitLab?

Tags: gitlab, pipeline

**How do I add a label to the GitLab pipelines when they run?**
This would be extremely helpful when you run a few nightly (scheduled) pipelines for different configurations on the main branch. For example, we run a nightly main branch with several submodules, each set at a point in their development (a commit point SHA) and I want to label that 'MAIN'. We run a second pipeline that I want to label 'HEADs', which is a result of pulling all of the HEAD's of the submodule to see if changes will break the main trunk when they are merged in.
Currently it shows:

- Last commit message.
- Pipeline #
- commit SHA
- Branch name
- 'Scheduled'

That is helpful, but it is very difficult to tell them apart because only the pipeline # changes between the pipelines.

Answer (score 5):

**I have good news!!**
Our friends at GitLab have been working on this feature. There is now a way to label your pipeline in release 15.5.1-ee.0!

It uses the **workflow** control with a new keyword **name**

```
workflow:
    name: 'Pipeline for branch: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
```

You can even use the *workflow:rules* pair to have different names for you pipeline:

```
variables:
    PIPELINE_NAME: 'Default pipeline name'

workflow:
    name: '$PIPELINE_NAME'
rules:
    - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
       variables:
           PIPELINE_NAME: 'MR pipeline: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH'
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_LABELS =~ /pipeline:run-in-ruby3/'
       variables:
           PIPELINE_NAME: 'Ruby 3 pipeline'
```

Find the docs here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflow

This feature is disabled by default in 15.5 because it is so new. 
You can enable the feature flag, which is named *pipeline_name*.

See this link to enable: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/feature_flags.html
(You need to use the Rails Console to enable it. Pretty easy.)

Note: Remember that the *workflow* keyword affects the entire pipeline instance.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to be officially supported with [GitLab 15.7](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2022/12/22/gitlab-15-7-released/#add-custom-names-to-pipelines-with-workflowname) (December 2022)

> ### Add custom names to pipelines with `workflow:name:`
>
> For some projects, the same pipeline can be configured to run differently for different variables or conditions, creating very distinct outcomes for successful pipelines.
> It can be hard for you to determine which version of that pipeline ran since there is no indication about the inputs used for that particular run.
> While labels like `scheduled` and `API` help, it is sometimes still difficult to identify specific pipelines.
>
> Now you can set a pipeline name using the keyword `workflow:name` to better identify the pipeline with string, a CI/CD variable, or a combination of both.
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowname) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/372538).

Note:

> If the name is an empty string, the pipeline is not assigned a name.
> A name consisting of only CI/CD variables could evaluate to an empty string if all the variables are also empty.

---

And, since [GitLab 16.3](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2023/08/22/gitlab-16-3-released/#expose-pipeline-name-as-a-predefined-cicd-variable) (August 2023):

> ### Expose pipeline name as a predefined CI/CD variable
>
> Pipeline names defined with the [`workflow:name`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#workflowname) keyword are now accessible via the predefined variable `$CI_PIPELINE_NAME`.
>
> [image: https://about.gitlab.com/images/16_3/workflow-name-image.png -- Expose pipeline name as a predefined CI/CD variable]
>
> See [Documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html) and [Issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/420002).